# Google Geocode web service certificate error - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: google-maps

I am connecting to google geocode web service from .NET code. It works perfectly in my local machine and when deployed in windows 2003 std. server, I am getting the below error.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Where can I get the certificate for Google web service? I tried downloading it from chrome by hitting the url and saved the certificate in a file and added to Trusted certificate store but still having same issue when the site is running.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.